# LoadError: UndefVarError: plot not defined in Julia

Tags: plot, julia, juno-ide

I have the following code in Julia:

```
#Pkg.add("Plots")
using Plots
plotly()
plot(1:5,1:5)
```

Julia Pro always returns me the following error:

```
LoadError: UndefVarError: plot not defined
```

What is causing this and how can I fix it?